# regular expression for url manager in yii is not working

Tags: regex, yii

enter image description hereI have used regular expression at url rules manager in my project and it's on yii framework. But it's not working. How to solve this problem??

I've written the `URL`  like,

```
< cat_id:\d+ >/< cat_name:[\w\-]+ >/buying-offer'=>'frontend/allCategory/index',
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the `regex` in your code, but you have some additional spaces, so you need to remove them:

```
'<cat_id:\d+>/<cat_name:[\w\-]+>/buying-offer'=>'frontend/allCategory/index'
```

By above code: `http://something/23/catName/buying-offer` will be replaced with `frontend/allCategory/index`

Comment: There is no need to escape the `-` inside the character class when you put it at the trailing. So  `[\w-]` will works as well, also you need to be sure that user used the preceding regex in a correct way with a correct syntax! anyway good explanation! ;-)

Comment: @Kasramvd Hey, buddy, I've just made a copy paste from the question. Anyway, thank you so much for your tips and consideration.